# Gnu autotools missing file depcomp

Tags: gnu, autotools, automake

I'm trying to write a program that builds with autotools, however I have run into a problem when I try to make it. Automake seems to rely on a file called depcomp. I was wondering what this file does, and what I should fill it with/how I should make it.

Comment: Your program does not build with autotools.  You use the autotools to create a build system which is used to build the program.  Perhaps this is a trivial distinction, perhaps that is what is meant by the phrase "a program that builds with autotools", but it is a distinction which has caused untold confusion and should be clarified.

Answer (score 7):

`depcomp` is installed by Automake itself when you run `automake --install` (or better, when you run `autoreconf -vfi`).  It is used to keep track of the **dep**endencies as a side-effect of **comp**ilation.